# Daily Shift Totals (6:05AM To 6:05PM)Dayshift and (6:05PM To 6:05AM)Nightshift

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my original SQL query. I want to modify it to show each day of the current month. I have that query below as well, but the results are wrong. The data is from (6:05AM to 6:05PM)Dayshift and (6:05PM to 6:05AM)Nightshift

Original SQL query

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Shift = 'Dayshift' THEN TotalWeight ELSE 0 END) AS DayshiftTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Shift = 'Nightshift' THEN TotalWeight ELSE 0 END) AS NightshiftTotal,
    SUM(TotalWeight) AS TotalWeight
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN CAST(DateTm AS TIME) >= '06:05:00' AND CAST(DateTm AS TIME) < '18:05:00' THEN 'Dayshift'
            ELSE 'Nightshift'
        END AS Shift,
        SUM(TotalWeight) AS TotalWeight
    FROM DryerHopperWeightTotal
    WHERE 
        (CAST(DateTm AS TIME) >= '06:05:00' AND CAST(DateTm AS TIME) < '18:05:00' AND DateTm >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), '06:05:00') AND DateTm < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), '18:05:00'))
        OR
        (CAST(DateTm AS TIME) >= '18:05:00' OR CAST(DateTm AS TIME) < '06:05:00') AND (DateTm >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), '18:05:00') - 1 AND DateTm < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), '06:05:00'))
    GROUP BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN CAST(DateTm AS TIME) >= '06:05:00' AND CAST(DateTm AS TIME) < '18:05:00' THEN 'Dayshift'
            ELSE 'Nightshift'
        END
) AS ShiftTotals;
```

Results from my original SQL query. This data is correct.

```
DayshiftTotal/NightshiftTotal/TotalWeight  
   215,450   /   346,530    / 561,980
```

Modified SQL Query

```
WITH ShiftTotalsCTE AS (
    SELECT
        FORMAT(DateTm, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS Date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTm AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:05' AND '18:05' THEN TotalWeight ELSE 0 END) AS DayShiftTotal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(DateTm AS TIME) NOT BETWEEN '06:05' AND '18:05' THEN TotalWeight ELSE 0 END) AS NightShiftTotal
    FROM DryerHopperWeightTotal (nolock)
    WHERE MONTH(DateTm) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(DateTm) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY FORMAT(DateTm, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
)

SELECT
    Date,
    DayShiftTotal,
    NightShiftTotal,
    COALESCE(DayShiftTotal, 0) + COALESCE(NightShiftTotal, 0) AS Total24Hours
FROM ShiftTotalsCTE
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Results from the modified SQL query

```
    Date   / DayshiftTotal/ NightshiftTotal/TotalWeight
02/16/2024 /   215,540    /     263,630    / 479,080
02/15/2024 /   274,270    /     253,410    / 527,680
02/14/2024 /   472,570    /     440,960    / 913,530
02/13/2024 /   394,480    /     219,670    / 614,150
02/12/2024 /   440,581    /     322,340    / 762,921
```

What I would like to see

```
    Date   / DayshiftTotal/ NightshiftTotal/TotalWeight
02/16/2024 /   215,450    /     346,530    / 561,980
```

This is the data from the table. Data goes between two dates

```
TotalWeight/ DateTm
Nightshift on the 15th 
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:05:07 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:10:07 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:15:07 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:20:07 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:25:07 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:30:07 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:35:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:40:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:45:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:50:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 18:55:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:00:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:05:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:10:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:15:08 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:20:09 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:25:09 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:30:09 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:35:09 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:40:09 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:45:09 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 19:50:09 CST 2024
3280.0,Thu Feb 15 19:55:10 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 20:00:10 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 20:05:10 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 20:10:10 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 20:15:10 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 20:20:10 CST 2024
350.0,Thu Feb 15 20:25:10 CST 2024
870.0,Thu Feb 15 20:30:11 CST 2024
5090.0,Thu Feb 15 20:35:11 CST 2024
4400.0,Thu Feb 15 20:40:11 CST 2024
4680.0,Thu Feb 15 20:45:11 CST 2024
4780.0,Thu Feb 15 20:50:11 CST 2024
2770.0,Thu Feb 15 20:55:11 CST 2024
4950.0,Thu Feb 15 21:00:11 CST 2024
4840.0,Thu Feb 15 21:05:11 CST 2024
5670.0,Thu Feb 15 21:10:12 CST 2024
2420.0,Thu Feb 15 21:15:12 CST 2024
1970.0,Thu Feb 15 21:20:12 CST 2024
2580.0,Thu Feb 15 21:25:12 CST 2024
1400.0,Thu Feb 15 21:30:12 CST 2024
1400.0,Thu Feb 15 21:35:12 CST 2024
1520.0,Thu Feb 15 21:40:12 CST 2024
4490.0,Thu Feb 15 21:45:12 CST 2024
3770.0,Thu Feb 15 21:50:13 CST 2024
3400.0,Thu Feb 15 21:55:13 CST 2024
4500.0,Thu Feb 15 22:00:13 CST 2024
2030.0,Thu Feb 15 22:05:13 CST 2024
1520.0,Thu Feb 15 22:10:13 CST 2024
1560.0,Thu Feb 15 22:15:13 CST 2024
1120.0,Thu Feb 15 22:20:13 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:25:13 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:30:14 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:35:14 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:40:14 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:45:14 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:50:14 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 22:55:14 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:00:14 CST 2024
120.0,Thu Feb 15 23:05:14 CST 2024
3440.0,Thu Feb 15 23:10:15 CST 2024
2170.0,Thu Feb 15 23:15:15 CST 2024
1810.0,Thu Feb 15 23:20:15 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:25:15 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:30:15 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:35:15 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:40:15 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:45:16 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:50:16 CST 2024
0.0,Thu Feb 15 23:55:16 CST 2024
1020.0,Fri Feb 16 00:00:16 CST 2024
4930.0,Fri Feb 16 00:05:16 CST 2024
5820.0,Fri Feb 16 00:10:18 CST 2024
5520.0,Fri Feb 16 00:15:18 CST 2024
5170.0,Fri Feb 16 00:20:18 CST 2024
5660.0,Fri Feb 16 00:25:18 CST 2024
3960.0,Fri Feb 16 00:30:18 CST 2024
5150.0,Fri Feb 16 00:35:18 CST 2024
5760.0,Fri Feb 16 00:40:18 CST 2024
5650.0,Fri Feb 16 00:45:19 CST 2024
5440.0,Fri Feb 16 00:50:19 CST 2024
4920.0,Fri Feb 16 00:55:19 CST 2024
5610.0,Fri Feb 16 01:00:19 CST 2024
2240.0,Fri Feb 16 01:05:19 CST 2024
980.0,Fri Feb 16 01:10:19 CST 2024
6310.0,Fri Feb 16 01:15:19 CST 2024
5710.0,Fri Feb 16 01:20:19 CST 2024
3900.0,Fri Feb 16 01:25:19 CST 2024
6290.0,Fri Feb 16 01:30:20 CST 2024
5820.0,Fri Feb 16 01:35:20 CST 2024
940.0,Fri Feb 16 01:40:20 CST 2024
5970.0,Fri Feb 16 01:45:20 CST 2024
5620.0,Fri Feb 16 01:50:20 CST 2024
3400.0,Fri Feb 16 01:55:20 CST 2024
3510.0,Fri Feb 16 02:00:20 CST 2024
5740.0,Fri Feb 16 02:05:20 CST 2024
5740.0,Fri Feb 16 02:10:21 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 02:15:21 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 02:20:21 CST 2024
4490.0,Fri Feb 16 02:25:21 CST 2024
5820.0,Fri Feb 16 02:30:21 CST 2024
4670.0,Fri Feb 16 02:35:21 CST 2024
1990.0,Fri Feb 16 02:40:21 CST 2024
7980.0,Fri Feb 16 02:45:21 CST 2024
5930.0,Fri Feb 16 02:50:22 CST 2024
4010.0,Fri Feb 16 02:55:22 CST 2024
6070.0,Fri Feb 16 03:00:22 CST 2024
6000.0,Fri Feb 16 03:05:22 CST 2024
3360.0,Fri Feb 16 03:10:22 CST 2024
5810.0,Fri Feb 16 03:15:22 CST 2024
5810.0,Fri Feb 16 03:20:22 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 03:25:22 CST 2024
4990.0,Fri Feb 16 03:30:22 CST 2024
5690.0,Fri Feb 16 03:35:23 CST 2024
4290.0,Fri Feb 16 03:40:23 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 03:45:23 CST 2024
2620.0,Fri Feb 16 03:50:23 CST 2024
5670.0,Fri Feb 16 03:55:23 CST 2024
5910.0,Fri Feb 16 04:00:23 CST 2024
790.0,Fri Feb 16 04:05:23 CST 2024
2060.0,Fri Feb 16 04:10:23 CST 2024
6000.0,Fri Feb 16 04:15:25 CST 2024
6360.0,Fri Feb 16 04:20:25 CST 2024
560.0,Fri Feb 16 04:25:25 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 04:30:25 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 04:35:25 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 04:40:25 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 04:45:25 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 04:50:25 CST 2024
4440.0,Fri Feb 16 04:55:26 CST 2024
5790.0,Fri Feb 16 05:00:26 CST 2024
4770.0,Fri Feb 16 05:05:26 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:10:26 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:15:26 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:20:26 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:25:26 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:30:26 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:35:27 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 05:40:27 CST 2024
4170.0,Fri Feb 16 05:45:27 CST 2024
6250.0,Fri Feb 16 05:50:27 CST 2024
4550.0,Fri Feb 16 05:55:27 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:00:27 CST 2024

Dayshift on the 16th
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:05:27 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:10:27 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:15:28 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:20:28 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:25:28 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:30:28 CST 2024
4350.0,Fri Feb 16 06:35:28 CST 2024
5150.0,Fri Feb 16 06:40:28 CST 2024
5480.0,Fri Feb 16 06:45:28 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:50:28 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 06:55:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:00:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:05:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:10:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:15:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:20:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:25:29 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 07:30:29 CST 2024
2030.0,Fri Feb 16 07:35:30 CST 2024
4780.0,Fri Feb 16 07:40:30 CST 2024
5100.0,Fri Feb 16 07:45:30 CST 2024
3640.0,Fri Feb 16 07:50:30 CST 2024
4090.0,Fri Feb 16 07:55:30 CST 2024
5070.0,Fri Feb 16 08:00:30 CST 2024
5260.0,Fri Feb 16 08:05:30 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 08:10:32 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 08:15:32 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 08:20:32 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 08:25:32 CST 2024
1290.0,Fri Feb 16 08:30:32 CST 2024
5320.0,Fri Feb 16 08:35:32 CST 2024
5080.0,Fri Feb 16 08:40:32 CST 2024
4700.0,Fri Feb 16 08:45:32 CST 2024
4600.0,Fri Feb 16 08:50:33 CST 2024
1540.0,Fri Feb 16 08:55:33 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 09:00:33 CST 2024
2900.0,Fri Feb 16 09:05:33 CST 2024
5210.0,Fri Feb 16 09:10:33 CST 2024
5150.0,Fri Feb 16 09:15:33 CST 2024
4960.0,Fri Feb 16 09:20:33 CST 2024
4980.0,Fri Feb 16 09:25:33 CST 2024
5200.0,Fri Feb 16 09:30:33 CST 2024
4880.0,Fri Feb 16 09:35:34 CST 2024
4760.0,Fri Feb 16 09:40:34 CST 2024
5480.0,Fri Feb 16 09:45:34 CST 2024
4690.0,Fri Feb 16 09:50:34 CST 2024
4520.0,Fri Feb 16 09:55:34 CST 2024
4860.0,Fri Feb 16 10:00:34 CST 2024
4530.0,Fri Feb 16 10:05:34 CST 2024
5210.0,Fri Feb 16 10:10:34 CST 2024
5290.0,Fri Feb 16 10:15:35 CST 2024
3750.0,Fri Feb 16 10:20:35 CST 2024
1970.0,Fri Feb 16 10:25:35 CST 2024
4640.0,Fri Feb 16 10:30:35 CST 2024
4700.0,Fri Feb 16 10:35:35 CST 2024
4900.0,Fri Feb 16 10:40:35 CST 2024
4460.0,Fri Feb 16 10:45:36 CST 2024
5310.0,Fri Feb 16 10:50:36 CST 2024
5090.0,Fri Feb 16 10:55:37 CST 2024
5300.0,Fri Feb 16 11:00:37 CST 2024
5190.0,Fri Feb 16 11:05:37 CST 2024
5190.0,Fri Feb 16 11:10:37 CST 2024
1770.0,Fri Feb 16 11:15:37 CST 2024
4560.0,Fri Feb 16 11:20:37 CST 2024
5120.0,Fri Feb 16 11:25:37 CST 2024
4450.0,Fri Feb 16 11:30:37 CST 2024
4140.0,Fri Feb 16 11:35:37 CST 2024
4810.0,Fri Feb 16 11:40:38 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 11:45:38 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 11:50:38 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 11:55:38 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:00:38 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:05:38 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:10:39 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:15:39 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:20:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:25:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:30:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:35:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:40:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:45:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:50:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 12:55:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:00:40 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:05:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:10:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:15:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:20:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:25:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:30:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:35:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:40:41 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:45:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:50:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 13:55:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:00:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:05:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:10:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:15:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:20:42 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:25:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:30:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:35:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:40:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:45:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:50:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 14:55:43 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:00:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:05:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:10:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:15:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:20:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:25:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:30:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:35:44 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:40:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:45:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:50:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 15:55:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:00:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:05:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:10:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:15:45 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:20:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:25:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:30:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:35:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:40:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:45:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:50:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 16:55:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:00:46 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:05:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:10:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:15:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:20:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:25:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:30:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:35:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:40:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:45:47 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:50:48 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 17:55:48 CST 2024
0.0,Fri Feb 16 18:00:48 CST 2024
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti how would I do that?

Comment: You should post some original data as well, so it's possible to run and test your queries

Comment: @siggemannen how do I post the original data on here?

Comment: Just put a couple of rows from DryerHopperWeightTotal the same way you create the markdown tables so one understand what the problem is when running for those months

Comment: @siggemannen I posted some of the original data

Comment: You need to also show us the results you wish to receive so always 3 sets of data, raw (sample not production) data, actual results, and desired results.

Comment: @DaleK I posted what I would like to see. When looking through the data, it seems DayshiftTotal is correct. Its the NightshiftTotal that is off. I assume it is because it goes to the next day that is the problem.

Comment: Your sample data is too huge for anybody to work on it. Reduce it such that it is sufficient to demonstrate your issue. Aldo please ensure that the expected result is corresponded to the sample data that you have posted, so that others is able to verify the logic and query. Also explain the necessary logic / rules / calculation etc. required to handle the Night Shift data.

Comment: If using SQL Server 2022, the `DATEBUCKET()` function may be useful for mapping date/times to the shift start - `DATEBUCKET(ConvertedDateTm, minute, 720, '2024-01-01 0605') AS ShiftStart`. This can be wrapped in a `CROSS APPLY` and then referenced by the `GROUP BY` and final select list. This would group the entire night shift, which crosses midnight, into the same shift. Your month range filter can also be adjusted to align with shift boundaries - `WHERE ConvertedDateTm >= DATETOMEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1, 6, 5, 0, 0) AND ConvertedDateTm < DATETIMEFROMPARTS(year, month + 1, 1, 6, 5, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @squirrel I updated the sample data and the other info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly group your data, you need to first map the date/times to shifts and then shifts to days. If using SQL Server 2022, you can use the `DATE_BUCKET()` function to map the date/times to shifts starting at 18:05 and 06:05.

It appears that you wish to count the entire night shift as part of the ending day's activity. This can be accomplished by calculating the shift-end as shift-start plus 12 hours and truncating to date. That date is then used to group the data.

It then becomes a simple matter of using *conditional aggregation* to calculate the night shift, day shift, and overall totals based on the time portion of the shift-start.

The overall date range also needs to be adjusted to take into account that the 18:05 - 24:00 of the last day of the month needs to be included in the following month's totals. This is done by adjusting both the start and end dates back to 18:05 of the previous day.

It is also best to calculate a start/end date/time range up front instead of using `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions. When dealing with date/time ranges, it is common to calculate an *inclusive* start date/time and an *exclusive* end date/time. This allows the filter condition to be something like `WHERE dt >= @start and dt < @end` without having to perform date truncations or conversions, which allows for efficient index usage.

The result would be something like:

```
-- Calculate inclusive start and exclusive end dates for the current month
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = DATETRUNC(month, GETDATE()) -- '2024-02-01'
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = DATEADD(month, 1, @FromDate) -- Exclusive

-- Since a night shift is applied to the following (ending) day, we need
-- to adjust the start/end date/times to be 18:05 on the preceding day.
DECLARE @MinutesAdjust INT = -1440 + 18 * 60 + 5 -- Minus 1 day plus 18:05
DECLARE @FromDateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(minute, @MinutesAdjust, @FromDate)
DECLARE @ToDateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(minute,  @MinutesAdjust, @ToDate)

DECLARE @ShiftOrigin DATETIME = '1900-01-01 06:05' -- DATE_BUCKET reference date/time
DECLARE @ShiftMinutes INT = 12 * 60  -- 12 hours shifts
  
SELECT
    D.ShiftEndDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.ShiftStartTime = '06:05' THEN W.TotalWeight ELSE 0 END) AS DayShiftTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.ShiftStartTime = '18:05' THEN W.TotalWeight ELSE 0 END) AS NightShiftTotal,
    SUM(W.TotalWeight) AS TotalWeight
FROM DryerHopperWeightTotal W
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATE_BUCKET(minute, @ShiftMinutes, W.DateTm, @ShiftOrigin) AS ShiftStart
) S
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CAST(S.ShiftStart AS DATE) AS ShiftStartDate,
        CAST(S.ShiftStart AS TIME) AS ShiftStartTime,
        CAST(DATEADD(hour, 12, S.ShiftStart) AS DATE) AS ShiftEndDate
) D
WHERE W.DateTm >=  @FromDateTime AND W.DateTm < @ToDateTime
GROUP BY D.ShiftEndDate
ORDER BY D.ShiftEndDate DESC
```

The above uses `DATE_TRUNC()` AND `DATE_BUCKET()` functions only available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions of SQL Server, the following equivalent calculations can be used:

```
...
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
...
    SELECT DATEADD(minute,
                  DATEDIFF(minute, @ShiftOrigin, W.DateTm) / @ShiftMinutes * @ShiftMinutes,
                  @ShiftOrigin
                 ) AS ShiftStart
...
```

Results for the given sample data:

| ShiftEndDate | DayShiftTotal | NightShiftTotal | TotalWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-16 | 215450.0 | 346530.0 | 561980.0 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1jiruGf_) for a demo.

The same query but with additional (since trimmed) data from your earlier post data merged in is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/76f0LS41) with the following results:

| ShiftEndDate | DayShiftTotal | NightShiftTotal | TotalWeight | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-16 | 215450.0 | 346530.0 | 561980.0 | Matches earlier desired results |
| 2024-02-15 | 274270.0 | 318460.0 | 592730.0 | Matches earlier desired results |
| 2024-02-14 | 460370.0 | 0.0 | 460370.0 | Data is incomplete |

These results only partially match the desired results because sample data from 14 Feb is incomplete and sample data from 14 Feb is absent.

Comment: @T N  I must have a older version of sql,, that worked!